Why does the NIV translate "κεχαριτωμένη" as "highly favoured" in Luke 1:28?
Luke 1:28:

Καὶ [And] εἰσελθὼν [having entered] πρὸς [to] αὐτὴν [her] εἶπεν [he said], Χαῖρε [Greetings], κεχαριτωμένη [full of grace / having been graced / highly favored], ὁ [the] Κύριος [Lord] μετὰ [with] σοῦ [you].

NIV:

The angel went to her [Mary] and said, ‘Greetings, you who are highly favored! The Lord is with you.’

In this question, I asked about how Catholics understand the Greek word "κεχαριτωμένη" in Luke 1:28, and Ken Graham provided a detailed answer from a Catholic point of view which explained why Catholics prefer to translate this as "full of grace".
However, the NIV does not follow this translation, instead translating it as "[you who are] highly favored".  What is the significance of the NIV choosing this specific translation and what is the linguistic or theological basis of their translation?

This question probably belongs on biblical hermeneutics.

The word κεχαριτωμενη is a participle derived from the verb χαιρω (chairo; hence English words like charity and charisma).
If you put stock in the proto-indo-european line of origin for the Koine Greek language (among others), χαιρω (chairo) means to rejoice or be glad and so the participle in question means "having been given joy to".

Our verb χαιρω (chairo) stems from the widely attested ancient Proto-Indo-European root "gher-" which meant to like or want, and which also gave us the word "whore." This may in turn help to explain why prostitution plays such a major part in the Bible — the very tribe of Judah including Jesus via Perez came about from an act of prostitution (Genesis 38:12-30). Prostitution, of course, seeks to simulate the joy that comes with a lasting union...but its core idea, namely that joy comes from union, is actually spot on. - Abarim Publications

There are two supposed identical roots of χαιρω (chairo); namely gher, which spawns two different collections of word groups:  One group has to do with collectivity and union such as choir and court and the other has to do with garden, farming, etc.
The angel in the verse in question actually says something along the lines of; "You rejoice (imperative form of χαιρω (chairo)), having been given joy to (participle form of χαιρω (chairo)), the Lord within you.".
After a long and winding article, ultimately the word in question is used of Mary who bears within her womb the one true vine into which God's people will be grafted, pruned, and harvested.  She bears the Great Shepherd who gathers and tends one flock.  The word reflects the joy imparted by the union of God and man and this union taking place within the womb of a virgin.
You rejoice, having been given joy, the Lord within you.
With these things in mind it is easy to see how the English renderings of both "highly favored" and "full of grace" are both appropriate and somewhat limited in expressing the large scope of the roots of this word.  Who is not highly favored who has been given joy by the very presence of the Lord within?  Who, in similar fashion, is not full of grace, especially if that grace is the unmerited favor of having been given the joy of God's indwelling presence.
